# How to create a SOAP request in EWS?

Tags: soap, xmlhttprequest, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I've got such kind of class with required login, password, url and domain:

```
class Service
{
    public ExchangeService service;

    public void Connect()
    {
        const string exchangeUser = "login";
        const string exchangePassword = "password";
        const string exchangeUri = "url";
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeUser, exchangePassword, "domain");
        service.Url = new Uri(exchangeUri);
    }
}
```

And I need to add such method as CreateAppointment()

```
public void CreateAppointment()
{
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
        appointment.Subject = "Team building exercise";
        appointment.Body = "Let's learn to really work as a team and then have lunch!";
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(4);
        appointment.Location = "Some city";
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("somebody@something.com");
        appointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;

        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
}
```

Save() method doesn't work because of some reasons for creating service and appointment objects. So I need to rewrite this method using xml request. And I've got an example of SOAP request from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx

How could I insert the SOAP request instead of CreateAppointment() method? I've got no idea what to do with xml code to make it work as CreateAppointment() method.

Comment: Try using something like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2016/04/14/testing-sample-which-uses-httpwebrequest-to-do-a-post-to-ews/ . You need to pick a class or library you want to use we httpclient can also do it but you still need to write all the code to parse the result manually. But why don't you fix the reason the EWS Managed API isn't working that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @GlenScales Thank you! I solved this problem using this article https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2011/01/28/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-in-net-4-0-c-without-using-the-wsdl-or-proxy-classes/ , but I fixed it a little bit to make it work fine in .NET Core.